Sqlalchemy как получить экземпляр только что созданного объекта без дополнителного запроса
session.add(Project(title=title, description=description, owner=user.id))
await session.commit()

Создаю и сохраняю в бд экземпляр, но далее в коде мне нужен id только что созданного объекта. Можно ли как-то получить созданный объект в переменную без запроса с фильтрацией к бд?
